# Overlaying transparent box css in grid

Tags: css, overlay, transparent

I have an image over which I want to display some text information. I have a div below it that  contains the information, with a transparent background and everything formatted. I can use `margin-top: -50%` to pull it up over the image, but since I'm using a grid ([1140](http://cssgrid.net/)), when the screen is shrunk things don't match up.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML (in Slim)

```
.fourcol
  .book
    img src="#{book.image_url}"
    .book-info
      header
        h4.title
          = book.title
        h6.author
          = book.author
      p.description
        = book.description
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.book-info {
      margin-top: -62%;
      padding: 1em;
      padding-bottom: 1.5em;
      float: left;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: .8; }
```

How can the book-info scale so it's bottom is always at the bottom of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` on `.book-info` to position it in relation to `.book`:

```
.book {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; /* to clear the floats inside */
}

.book-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bg28d/5/).

Comment: Absolute messes up positioning in relation to the grid

Comment: It shouldn't, with `position: relative` on `.book`. Could you setup an example on http://jsfiddle.net/? It would be easier for us to understand what you're looking for, and the problems you're facing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bg28d/1/ I only did one book. In jsfiddle it doesn't even overlay, but locally it does. EDIT: changing the negative `margin-top` fixes that a bit. Widths still off

Comment: Please see my update and demo (based on the 1 book fiddle). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Do you see at one point (if you resize) the info suddenly jumps to full width. Why is that? (just curious, your demo works very well!) Thanks!

Comment: I think it's the grid. Can you give your `.book` div fixed dimensions? That would fix it for sure.

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of a responsive grid right? It works when the grid is closer to its max so I think that's good enough

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the div containing the information, in a wrapper which also contains the image.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #info 
    {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 4%;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    #theImage
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #wrapper
    {
         width: 15%;
         height: 15%;
         overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="theImage" src="..." alt="" />
    <div id="info">Information about the image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So can .book be that wrapper? All that is in there is the picture and the description

Comment: @Chris Yes, as long as .book is scalable within your grid.

Comment: This somewhat works, though when the banners across the book show up they aren't aligned (they are different sizes because of varying descriptions)